# How to generate working indexes for MacOS Help on Mojave and Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, macos-catalina

This is an "answer you own question" contribution.

I have been struggling for a day trying to get anchor to work in `NSHelpManager` system on 10.15, in order to be able to open a given help page with the `openHelpAnchor:inBook:` method.

Apple documentation for help system is old and have not been updated for a while.
The `hiutil` man page give a hint, stating :

> Spotlight help indices are required in macOS Mojave or later.

But using any of the two formats available did not work by itself.

So I had to reverse engineer by browsing the help ressources of Xcode itself to find the solution.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to generate **two** index files, one for each format, into the `.lproj`folder :

```
hiutil -I corespotlight -Cf help.cshelpindex -a -s fr -l fr .
hiutil -I lsm -Cf help.helpindex -a -s fr -l fr .
```

Then, **and this is the undocumented key**, one needs to add an entry into the help `info.plist` :

```
<key>HPDBookCSIndexPath</key>
<string>help.cshelpindex</string>
```

along with the traditional documented `HPDBookIndexPath` entry.

Et voilà.